# Not able to get Record ID from record

Tags: apex, class, standardcontroller, id

I am not sure why but i tried each and every step to get ID of Current record in Apex class but not getting it.

Class :

```
Public Class TestController{

public String bundleId{get;set;}

public TestController(ApexPages.StandardController Controller){        
    bundleId = Controller.getId();
    system.debug('====bundleId===='+bundleId);
}
```

VF page :

`<apex:page standardController="Bundle__c" extensions="TestController">`

Comment: Are you passing Id in URL. If possible share your page URL.

Comment: `https://c.cs26.visual.force.com/apex/TestProduct?bundleid=a0B21000001SSzP`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change your URL

```
https://c.cs26.visual.force.com/apex/TestProduct?id=a0‌​B21000001SSzP
```

If you are using different parameter name then you need to get the value using `getpararmeters()`

```
String parameterValue = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('parameterName');
```

Comment: Okay. and what if i am not using any different parameter and use as it is (id) ??

Comment: @Nihar in that case your existing code will work.

Comment: I did it several time but not sure why i was not able to do it..anyways thanks man !! :)

Comment: @Nihar glad to know I could help.

Answer (score -1):

Use standardcontroller on vf page

use 
bundleId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('bundleid')

or Change url parameter from bundleid to id

Comment: Used it already

Comment: See, Edited QUestion

Comment: use 
bundleId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')

Comment: use 
bundleId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('bundleid')

or Change url parameter from bundleid to id